# Counting occurrences of dynamic (spilled) array elements in a table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic, user-defined-functions

I'm using the new dynamic result functions like unique, filter, sort, A6#, etc. I like that they right size to the number of items they return.

I have a large data set in an Excel table (hundreds of columns and thousands of rows).  I've extracted the unique values of one column that meet a criterion into a dynamic array using the unique/filter functions without issue.

Now I want to count the occurrences of each of the returned values in a dynamic way so that the range of the returned values scales with the number of unique values that are dynamically returned by the unique function.  I can use the count function around a filter function to count the values one at a time, but the result is not dynamic, requiring me to manually copy/delete the function into the correct number of cells.

In summary, I'm looking for a way to count items in a table column that meet a criterion and are equal to all the values in a dynamic array.  The result dimensions should agree with the dimensions of the dynamic array.

I started with some sample data in a table:

| Color | Type | Cost | Criteria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| Blue | 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| Red | 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| Yellow | 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| Orange | 1 | 3 | FALSE |
| Red | 2 | 1 | TRUE |
| Orange | 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| Yellow | 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| Orange | 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| Blue | 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| Red | 1 | 3 | TRUE |
| Blue | 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| Yellow | 2 | 1 | TRUE |
| Red | 2 | 3 | FALSE |
| Red | 2 | 1 | FALSE |

(Color  Type    Cost    Criteria
Red 1   1   TRUE
Blue    2   2   FALSE
Red 1   3   TRUE
Yellow  1   2   TRUE
Orange  1   3   FALSE
Red 2   1   TRUE
Orange  2   2   FALSE
Yellow  1   3   TRUE
Orange  2   2   FALSE
Blue    1   1   TRUE
Red 1   3   TRUE
Blue    2   2   FALSE
Yellow  2   1   TRUE
Red 2   3   FALSE
Red 2   1   FALSE)

The desired output is a range with two columns, Unique colors where the criteria is true, and number of occurrences where that color appears, and the criteria is true.

Generating the first column was simple:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Color],Table1[Criteria]))
```

In this example the function returns a three-row single column:
Red
Yellow
Blue
It is simple to count the number of occurrences of a single member of that range with a formula that returns a single cell:

```
=COUNT(FILTER(Table1[Cost],Table1[Criteria]*(Table1[Color]=H10)))
```

Where I used Cost as it is numeric and works better with Count, and H10 is one of the cells in the dynamic array above 'Red' for example.

This function accurately counts what I want, but it does not shrink and expand as the number of colors returned to the table above changes, so I must go in and delete/copy the formula to the appropriate range. As my users will change the criteria column constantly, this leaves the two columns of different lengths often.

Next I converted this formula to the LET version which gave the same result.

```
=LET(lookup,H10,in,Table1[Color],cnt,Table1[Cost],crit,Table1[Criteria],
COUNT(FILTER(cnt,crit*(lookup=in))))
```

I then replaced the reference to the color in the formula (H10) with the dynamic array containing it (H10#), the result was a single cell with a value of 0.

I then deleted the count function leaving just the filter function and it returned NA.  So, the filter function did not handle the H10# reference and returned a single value, NA.

I decided I needed to write a counting function that could handle the dynamic reference, I ended up with:

```
Public Function DynamicCount(SearchIn, LookFor As Variant As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
Dim idx As Long

    ReDim arr(1 To LookFor.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
        
    For idx = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        arr(idx, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchIn, LookFor(idx, 1))
    Next idx
    
    DynamicCount = arr
    
End Function
```

I tested this first without the criteria, simply entering:

```
=DynamicCount(Table1[Color],H10#)
```

This worked returning the following spilling from a single cell:

6
3
3

I then tried applying the criteria using:

```
=DynamicCount(FILTER(Table1[Color],Table1[Criteria]),H10#)
```

This returned a value error!  I'm not sure what is going on.  I evaluated just the Filter part:

```
=FILTER(Table1[Color],Table1[Criteria])
```

This returned a spilled list of 8 colors as expected.
After playing with the vba code a little, I think the problem is that the filter function is converting a range to a variant array.  Not sure how to work with them.  Did some msgbox debugging and when the SearchIn parameter is a Variant (as opposed to a range) It seems to crash on the following line.

`arr(idx, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchIn, LookFor(idx, 1))`

Any help would be appreciated, either with accessing variant arrays or other ways to tackle the problem.  There must be an easier way...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> -- No `VBA` required as well without any <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper functions!!

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, FILTER(HSTACK(Table_1[Color],Table_1[Criteria]),Table_1[Criteria]),
     Ψ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, DROP(α,,1),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(Ψ,MMULT(N(Ψ=TOROW(Ψ)),φ))))
```

---

Or, a bit shorter way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, HSTACK(Table_1[Color],MMULT(N(Table_1[Color]=TOROW(Table_1[Color])),Table_1[Criteria])),
     UNIQUE(FILTER(α, DROP(α,,1))))
```

---

Comment: This didn't work on my system, it gave a #VALUE! Error (even after I changed the table name to Table1).  I think the problem was a lack of a conversion from boolean to integer in the second array in the MMULT parameters.  While playing around with this I found some unexpected behavior in the N function.  Basically, if I passed it the array the way you did it returned an array as expected, and if I passed it a single value it returned a single value as expected, but when I passed it a vector it returned a single value.  (I was trying to use N(Table1[Criteria]) as parameter 2 in the MMULT call.

Comment: Hi, @PythonNewbie23 can you show me a screenshot

Comment: So, until I understand what is going on with N, I decided not to use it.  So to convert from boolean to integer, I just multiply the vector or array by the single value 1.  That seems to work, although I'm not sure if it is as efficient at N.  So I ended up with the function:  =LET(
     α, HSTACK(Table1[Color],MMULT((Table1[Color]=TOROW(Table1[Color]))*1,(Table1[Criteria]*1))),
     UNIQUE(FILTER(α, DROP(α,,1))))   That seems to work.  Thanks for the help @Mayukh Bhattacharya

Comment: @PythonNewbie23 absolutely correct. You can also use `+0` or *`1` or `/1` or `--` so `N()` function _returns a number when given a value. **The N function can be used to convert TRUE and FALSE to 1 and 0 respectively.** When given a text value, the N function returns zero_

Comment: Here is a table of the problem, top row shows function in cell below it.  |Function |=Table1[Criteria] |=N(BG47#) |=N(Table1[Criteria]) |=Table1[Criteria]*1
|Function Row |TRUE |1 |1 |1|  |--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|  
|Spilled to these rows |FALSE | | |0|
|Spilled to these rows |TRUE | | |1|
|Spilled to these rows |TRUE | | |1|
|Spilled to these rows |FALSE | | |0|
|Spilled to these rows |TRUE | | |1|
|Spilled to these rows |FALSE | | |0|
|Spilled to these rows |TRUE | | |1|
|Spilled to these rows |FALSE | | |0|
|Spilled to these rows |TRUE | | |1|
...@Mayukh

Comment: @PythonNewbie23 why do you enter formula in the header. Have you applied those formulas in a `Structured References` aka `Tables` then none of the solutions would work as they will `Spill` and `#Spill` is not supported in `Structured References`

Comment: Not sure how to add a screenshot and the comment does not have room for the whole example.    =Table1[Criteria] results in a spilled column of true/false values.  =N(BG47#) (BG47 is the cell containing the previous function) returns 1 (unspilled, single cell).  =N(Table1[Criteria]) also returns a single 1.  =Table1[Criteria]*1 returns a column of 1's and 0's corresponding to the true/false values in Table1[Criteria].

Comment: I understand what is the issue now, you are having the criteri as `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `1` and `0` right is that so, if yes, then those needs to be parsed using `double unary` or multiply with `1` or add `0` or divide by `1`, try this now: `=LET(α, HSTACK(Table1[Color],MMULT(N(Table1[Color]=TOROW(Table1[Color])),--Table1[Criteria])),UNIQUE(FILTER(α, DROP(α,,1))))`

Comment: Also if you want a `LAMBDA()` variant then could do this `=HSTACK(UNIQUE(Table1[Color]),MAP(UNIQUE(Table1[Color]),LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=Table1[Color])*Table1[Criteria]))))` this will return `Orange` as well, to exclude we can wrap within `LET()` to `FILTER()` out.

Comment: Here you can try this as well: `=LET(a,HSTACK(UNIQUE(Table1[Color]),MAP(UNIQUE(Table1[Color]),LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=Table1[Color])*Table1[Criteria])))),FILTER(a,DROP(a,,1)))`

Comment: <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XUNg5od.png">

Comment: Yes the problem seems to be that the criteria are logical values not integers.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PythonNewbie23 yes thanks for the image, so as i said you need to coerce them using by any of these `double unary or multiply with 1 or add 0 or divide by 1` since those are `BOOLEAN VALUES` where `TRUE` means `1` and `FALSE` means `0` , i assume you know all this, but i should explain still since i am giving an answer to you. The `N()` will not work in that way, you need to use a `+` sign like this `=N(+Table1[Criteria])` to spill it, wait i will comment a screenshot

Comment: @PythonNewbie23 please check this it will certainly help **[N()<--Click Here To View](https://imgur.com/gallery/pudZqV0)** . You may like to read this as well **[here read](https://exceljet.net/videos/boolean-operations-in-array-formulas)**

Answer (score 0):

Try `BYROW` like this - no VBA necessary:

```
=LET(uniqueColors,UNIQUE(FILTER(table1[Color],table1[Criteria])),
     cntByColor,BYROW(uniqueColors,LAMBDA(r,SUMPRODUCT((table1[Color]=r)*(table1[Criteria])))),
     HSTACK(uniqueColors,cntByColor))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ike, that helps a lot.  I knew there must have been a better way, I'd never used BYROW before.  I ended up with:                                                                                      
     =LET(
         FilteredColors,FILTER(Table1[Color],Table1[Criteria]),
         UniqueColors,UNIQUE(FilteredColors),
         NColors,BYROW(UniqueColors,LAMBDA(r,SUM((FilteredColors=r)^2))),
     HSTACK(UniqueColors,NColors))

Comment: I changed SUMPRODUCT to SUM and tried to avoid the array multiplication you had in SUMPRODUCT by defining FilteredColors, but I had to do the multiplication inside the SUM to get it to work so I just squared the test vector.  Any idea why the multiplication is required inside the SUM?